# how to write oop javascript (with inheritance) in JetBrains Webstorm/PHPStorm to get autocompletion/intellisense

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Can someone write an example, of OOP JS code, i assume with annotations, where JetBrains IDEs can recognize inheritance? 
e.g.

```
class Animal: 
 prop: weight
 method: run()

class Cat extends Animal:
 prop: name
 method: eat()
```

so i want that Webstorm/PHPStorm autocompletes and shows info (ctrl+q) for such things:

```
 Cat.prototype.eat= function(){
     this.weight; //should be recognized as inherited property
 }

 var cat = new Cat();
 cat.run(); //should be recognized as inherited method
```

What is the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following will work without any annotations:

```
var Animal = function () {
    this.weight = 0;
    this.run = function () {
    }
    return this;
};
var Cat = function () {
    this.name = "Tom";
    this.eat = function () {
        return "Nyam"
    }
    return this;
}

Cat.prototype = new Animal();
var cat = new Cat();

cat.run()
```

this way also works:

```
function Shape() {
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
}

// superclass method
Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
    this.x += x;
    this.y += y;
    console.info('Shape moved.');
};

// Rectangle - subclass
function Rectangle() {
    Shape.call(this); // call super constructor.
}

// subclass extends superclass
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;

var rect = new Rectangle();
```

Plus, you can use JSDoc here - see http://usejsdoc.org/tags-augments.html, for example